# Django) How to inquire field of another model in ManyToMany relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to inquire data field from model which contains another model in ManyToMany relationship.

For instance, I want to calculate total cost from `Dinner` model, which has ManyToMany relationship with `Menu` model. Here goes simplified code.

```
class Menu(models.Model):
    cost = models.IntegerField()

class Dinner(models.Model):
    menus = models.ManyToManyField(Menu)
    objects = DinnerManager()

class DinnerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_total_cost(self):
        total_cost = 0
        for each_menu in self.menus.all():
            total_cost += each_menu.cost
        return total_cost
```

So my question is this: how should I set

> for each_menu in self.menus.all():
>
> total_cost += each_menu.cost

these two lines to get my class method work?
(or if other parts is wrong, please let me know. I'm fairly new to django..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code would work fine, except that it belongs on the Dinner model, not the Manager. It's relating to *a specific dinner*, not dinners generally, and needs to calculate the value of the menu items related to that individual dinner.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For now, my class method is related to *specific dinner*. How could I relate `get_total_cost` function to Manager?

Comment: But I'm not sure why you would want to. What would that mean?

Comment: Oh I just got confused. If my function should work as I expected, it has to calculate the cost of individual dinners,right? Sorry to annoy you for my stupidity